# maxlength on a number input on Mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have a number type input field where I have a max limit on. The problem is max input works fine in the web but there is a problem with Android.

Even if you type eleven numbers it allows you to type special characters like ' -,+ ' etc. How can I prevent that to happen. The input field must take just 11 numbers.

Here's my code;

```js
function maxLengthCheck(object) {
  if (object.value.length > object.max.length)
    object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.max.length)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="abc" id="abcInput" placeholder="Some Placeholder" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" maxlength="11" min="1" max="99999999999" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to `parseFloat` and check if it's a number using `isNaN`:

```js
function maxLengthCheck(object) {
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(object.value))) {
    object.value="";
  }
  if (object.value.length > object.max.length) {
    object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.max.length)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="abc" id="abcInput" placeholder="Some Placeholder" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" maxlength="11" min="1" max="99999999999" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)">
```

Emptying the input in case of non-numeric input seems to be what Firefox on Mac does per default.